# Text Processing

Tags: linux, bash

I have a few folders named folder1 folder2 etc.. under a root folder. In each folder there are many xml files. In each xml file there are number of occurence of text patern  (in case of under folder1) folder1.xxx folder1.yyy . I want to replace all the folder1.xxx with just xxx and folder2.yyy with yyy etc. 
I know first I need to get all the folder list and process each files under each folder and replace the texts accordingly. I using Ubuntu linux distro I tried sed but didnt succeed. Could you show me a qucik way to do this no matter whether it perl or bash or any other script. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited as per your comment):

```
for dir in folder1 folder2; do
  sed -i "s/$dir\.//" $dir/*
done
```

What this will do is for each directory you list (the `folder1 folder2` bit) it will do a simple "stream edit" (`sed`) on every file in that directory and search for the directory name followed by a dot and replace it with nothing.

Comment: Womble xxx is any string (I want to replace "folder1." with "") and folders names are changing script must get all the folder names. Thanks

Comment: especially sed "-i" option what I looked for thanks. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mmv installed, you might try something like

```
for dir in *; do
    mmv "$dir/$dir*" "$1";
done
```

mmv should be part of most distributions, but is not installed by default some cases. I'm not sure if it is in Ubuntu.